# How to use select....as and concat in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called Student, the student table contains the id, first_name and last_name. I am trying to select and concatenate first_name and last_name and display the column as "Name". This is my query:

```
Student.select("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'Name'").find(201410204)
```

but it returns

```
SELECT  concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'Name' FROM `students` WHERE `students`.`id` = 201410204 LIMIT 1

#<Student id: nil>
```

but when i try to paste the query inside mysql workbench it return the student name that has the id 201410204 and the column name is "Name".

[Click to see the result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7aBH.png)

What's the problem about my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you two solutions, one by using the **`power of rails`** and other using the **`scalability of rails`**.

**1) (Using power of rails)**

In the `Student` model create a method named `full_name` and concatenate `first_name and last_name`.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
.....

def full_name
   "#{try(:first_name)} #{try(:last_name)}".to_s
end
.....
end
```

Now open console or any where you need,

```
student = Student.find(201410204)

student.full_name
```

thats it, you will get the full name.

**2) Using Scalability of rails, even can execute SQL queries.**

```
student = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) FROM students where students.id = 201410204")
```

It returns an array,now you can retrieve using,

`student.rows[0]`

Thats it, you will get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

You need to select the id as well:

```
Student.select(:id, "CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name").find(201410204)

2.4.1 :073 > Student.select(:id, "CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name").find(23000)
Student Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "students"."id", CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as name FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 23000], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Student id: 23000, name: "Joe Blow">
```

Answer (score 0):

With `select` you restrict the returned columns. Your query returns only the Column `Name`. `id` and all other columns are missing. In this case you get an instance of student where all attributes are `nil`. Only the attribute `Name` is set. When you try `Student.select("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'Name'").find(201410204).Name` you will see the right result.

When you want to get all attributes you have to extend your select like this `Student.select("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'Name', *").find(201410204)`

**Edit:**

I did check it for mysql on https://de.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/, I don't know why but you have to name `*` first.

`Student.select("*, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'Name'").find(201410204)`

Comment: Student.select("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'Name'", *).find(201410204) has a syntax error

Comment: Yes the quote has to be closed after the `*`. I did fix it.

Comment: thank  you but it returned an error again. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `students` WHERE `students`.`id` = 201410204 LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT  concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as 'Name', * FROM `students` WHERE `students`.`id` = 201410204 LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

One solution

In model Create A method

```
def full_name
   "#{self.try(:first_name)} #{self.try(:last_name)}"
end

Now 

Student.find(121).full_name
```